# how to compress back up files to < 10GB

Tags: backup, compression

I recently backed up a shared drive between ubuntu and windows for fear that windows will corrupt the contents again. The Back up files by deja dup takes around 120GB of space. I then compressed it to a tar.gz file but it's still around 100 GB. Is there a way to compress it down to 10GB?

I appreciate any suggestions as I am planning to upload it to google drive.

Thanks!

Comment: I see. What alternatives would I have then? I intend to upload the backup file to google drive as I have unlimited storage there. However, uploading a file that's 100GB takes 222 hours and I can't afford to wait for that.

Comment: See:  https://superuser.com/questions/591154/time-to-zip-very-large-100g-files where they are showing how to use gzip at compression vs time.  If you have maximum compression that is going to be about the smallest you are going to be able to get it without corrupting files.

Comment: Hmm, would it be fine to apply gzip on a .tar.gz file? I can leave it overnight while the compression is taking place...

Comment: "*would it be fine to apply gzip on a .tar**.gz** file?*" The file is already gzipped.  Any attempt at further compression will **increase** the file size.

Comment: @RonJohn You are correct, but I just did a run and on the first time I tested another gzip compression on the same file only had a .01% decrease, then on the next run it had a .01% increase.  So, yes, the more you gzip the more it will increase the size.

Comment: @Terrance similar things happen when you try to compress encrypted files.  That's because compression only works on repeating patterns of text, and encryption works very hard to eliminate *all* repeating patterns.  In compressed files, the only repeating patterns you'll find are in their dictionaries of repeating patterns.

Comment: @RonJohn Yep, I was actually just reading that.  Good call!  BTW, good answer below.  Too bad I already gave you my +1.  =)

Comment: I would suggest to give up the idea of online backup as you are factors away from reasonable data volume and transfer times. Instead, consider using an external drive (they come in TBs for moderate prices) and if you want protection from physical catastrophes, make a copy and locate it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> The Back up files by deja dup takes around 120GB of space. I then compressed it to a tar.gz file but it's still around 100 GB.

To make it smaller, you could try, from the command line:

```
TARBALL=yourbackup.tar
gunzip -c ${BASENAME}.gz | bzip2 -9 -c > ${TARBALL}.bz2
```

> Is there a way to compress it down to 10GB?

Probably not.  Compressors aren't magic. Specifically, they can't compress already-compressed files, and most video and audio files, PDFs, etc are already compressed.  The fact that gzip only shrank the tarball by 17% means that there's no way it'll get to 10GB.  You'll be lucky to get it to 80GB.

Comment: I am going to remember to use bzip2 from now on.  Good compression.  Testing a 233MB folder, gzip was able to compress it to 115MB, where bzip2 compressed it to 102MB.  =)

Comment: @Terrance also try `pbzip2` and `xz` (in package xz-utils).

Answer (score 0):

### 10 GB backup

There is probably only one way to shrink the backup size from around 120GB to 10 GB: **Select the most important data for a separate backup.**

There are several backup tools, that let you select directories and files, that you want to include in the backup. Some of them provide compression. You can start searching via this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem)

You can run this backup regularly.

### Full backup

You can backup your complete system once in a great while, for example after major system upgrades or once per year. And you can keep this backup in an external drive, that you store far from the computer (in case of fire or theft).